# Little White Eggs on African Marigold Flower

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, pests

I am in Southern New Jersey. Can anyone advise on what to do about these little white eggs on my African Marigold?

[image: picture of eggs]

[image]

**Update:** The sun came out a few hours later and dried up the eggs. But, the flower is dying while the other flowers seem fine. I pinched off the dying flower.

Comment: If the eggs are on little stalks then it’s probably lacewings- good carnivorous insects.